# Load a .gif (Image slow)

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I've implemented [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), on my project, but the problem is that it lags a lot, the image is mooving super slow, I do not want to use a `WebView` (if I have to, it'd be the last option), but I'd like if anyone of you have implemented for example an `Alert Dialog` with a `.gif` or something, and know what is the perfect size to load a `.gif` please, let me know.

I put the code but it's not necessary, because it's just one line.

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.raw.test).into(ivGif);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here if you want use Glide for load gif image:

```
Glide.with(context).load(myUrl)
                .thumbnail(Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.myThumbnail))
                .fitCenter()
                .crossFade()
                .into(imageView);
```

I'm suggest if you use Icon libs for load gif Image, because Icon libs load image better 2x times faster than Glide. But in terms of images quality Glide is better.
I post code use Icon libs for load gif image:

```
 Ion.with(this).load(myUrl).withBitmap().asBitmap()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, Bitmap result) {
                    // do something with your bitmap
                }
            });
```

Comment: I'll test it, what do you think it's better use a `WebView` or using a `Library`?

Comment: @Stuart2041 When you use webview for load gif image which will have  a lot of lag and image very low